# Wierd Javascript action on a Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I`ve made a modal form for a website, however, when you click for the first time, the form does not appear. But if you touch a link, or navigate a little at the website and try again. The form shows. It happens on all buttons I have.

The modal opens at the button saying: "INSCRICAO AQUI"

Besides that, everything is working fine.

Here is the URL
http://www.projetograndesmestres.com/

Comment: I tried and it's working the first time. I'm on chrome windows 10.

Comment: Weird, because for still the same and the owners also. Sometimes opens. But I`ve changed the buttons now, so it will work cuz it`s down the middle now. But thanks for looking at it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ogjql is this the problem that you are facing??

Comment: Yes it is, its still like that.